# Why won't my WPF style trigger work to only show the horizontal scroll bar when the mouse is over my ScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I want to create a ScrollView that only shows the horizontal scroll bar when the mouse is over it, so I tried the following (note how I simply try to trigger the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to Auto when the mouse is over and predefine my ScrollViewer to have a Disabled HorizontalScrollBarVisibility):

```
<Window x:Class="OnMouseOverStackPanel.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Triggers" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="I'm a content filler."/>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Style="{StaticResource Triggers}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">
                <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!"/>
                <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!"/>
                <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!"/>
                <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!"/>
                <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!"/>
                <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!"/>
                <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!"/>
                <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!"/>
                <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!"/>
                <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="I'm a content filler."/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Unfortunately this isn't working for me. How can I append triggers to this object to get it to work?

Comment: When you say it isn't working for you do you mean it shows the scrollbar when it shouldn't or it doesn't when it should?

Comment: @SimonBelanger It doesn't seem to ever show the scroll bar using the code above.

Comment: Well auto is only if one is need. Is one needed?  Try visible.

Comment: @Blam Yeah, its needed. Even with Visible it gives me the same problem.

Comment: Without the style and with HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" on the scroll viewer, the horizontal scroll bar does show up, as expected. I  only want it be visible when the mouse is over it, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set a property directly, then it takes precedence over the `Style` hence in your case the `Style` was never able to modify the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` which was set directly on the `ScrollViewer`.

So changes would be to remove setting `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` on the element and instead setting a default via the `Style` and let the trigger modify the default when it applies. It's generally good practice to specify a `Style` default when you have a trigger modifying a property of the element. You can set the default value to `Hidden` or `Disabled` or anything you choose ofc for default.

Try:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="Triggers"
          TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Button Grid.Row="0"
          Content="I'm a content filler." />
  <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
                Style="{StaticResource Triggers}"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <StackPanel Height="30"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!" />
      <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!" />
      <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!" />
      <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!" />
      <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!" />
      <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!" />
      <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!" />
      <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!" />
      <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!" />
      <Button Content="Hey, I'm a button!" />
    </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
  <Button Grid.Row="2"
          Content="I'm a content filler." />
</Grid>
```

Comment: You've opened my eyes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to get this to work is to remove the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" from your scrollviewer and put 2 states in your style.

```
    <Style x:Key="Triggers" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

This should give you the effect you are after.